# UnboundLocalError after sys.exit()

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./datalogger.py", line 208, in <module>
    calculateamounttosend()
  File "./datalogger.py", line 36, in calculateamounttosend
    return send_amount
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'send_amount' referenced before assignment
```

Line 208 is:

```
calculateamounttosend()
```

The function is:

```
def calculateamounttosend():
        wallet_balance = float(subprocess.check_output(['solarcoind', 'getbalance'], shell=False))
        if wallet_balance < 0.0005:
                print ("*******ERROR: wallet balance of {}SLR too low for reliable datalogging, add more SLR to wallet $
                time.sleep(10)
                sys.exit
        elif wallet_balance >= 10:
                send_amount = str(1)
                print ('Based on wallet balance of {} amount to send to self set to {} SLR') .format(wallet_balance, se$
        elif wallet_balance < 10 and wallet_balance >= 0.03:
                send_amount = str(0.01)
                print ('Based on wallet balance of {} amount to send to self set to {} SLR') .format(wallet_balance, se$
        else:
                send_amount = str(0.00001)
                print ("*******WARNING: low wallet balance of {}SLR, send amount of {} may result in higher TX fees****$
        return send_amount
```

When the wallet_balance is lower than 0.0005 it does the sys.exit(), but then is doesnt really stop, it seems to read the rest of the code and give the error.  Im unclear why Im getting the error if the program exited, and if I have the return, why its causing an issue anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call this function.
Replace `sys.exit` with `sys.exit()`

P.S. But it is realy bad to use this erxtremly exceptional type of app closing. Try to use return or smth like exceptions (it is very bad idea too, but better than sys.exit() in the middle of processing and you can print your debug messages).

Comment: The program must exit because there are not enough funds in the wallet to execute the program, but the user cannot effect a change to that from this program, they have to go to the target solarcoind and do something, this could take minutes, hours or weeks